# I am attempting to add phonegap to my local maven repository for an android application, I'm looking for help on the steps I took

Tags: android, maven, cordova

I originally found Nico's advice https://github.com/nicokruger/android-maven-phonegap/issues/1 as I was browsing to find a maven repository hosting the phonegap .jar file.

While this put me on the path to adding the jar to my local repository, I ran in to all sorts of issues (Maven newbie here) with errors such as:

- [Error]...Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (Tried adding -DgeneratePom=true to the command line, but this didn't help)
- [Error]...The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact

After working through the issues, I came up with these steps to install. However, when I look at my local .m2 repository I only see the pom file created below; no jar file is present.

Thanks!

#### Environment

- Windows 7
- Apache Maven 3.0.4
- Java version: 1.6.0_31, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.

#### Steps (Modified: These are the correct steps now. Thanks to Ryan)

1. Download phonegap 1.7.0 from http://phonegap.com/download
2. Extract to temp folder
3. Navigate to: temp/phonegap-phonegap-475bfd2/lib/android
4. Execute the following at a command prompt:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=cordova-1.7.0.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.cordova -DartifactId=phonegap -Dversion=1.7.0 -Dpackaging=jar
   ```
5. Phonegap (cordova-1.7.0.jar) should now be installed in your local Maven repository
6. In your project pom, add the following to your POM file:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.cordova</groupId>
     <artifactId>phonegap</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Was working with phonegap-2.0.0. And got this error 'Missing POM for org.apache.cordova:phonegap:jar:2.0.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the pom and use the [install-file goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) instead, like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=cordova-1.7.0.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.cordova -DartifactId=phonegap -Dversion=1.7.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I thought I had tried this....Thanks a million!
I'll update the question above to contain the correct steps for future reference