# add cordova plugin dependency to build.gradle

Tags: android, cordova, maven, cordova-plugins

I searched extensively but cannot not find the maven repository for org.apache.cordova.
I want to edit an existing plugin (from github) in android studio.

I have tried adding the dependency by jar file. But generating the jar fails when "ant jar" with complex errors (cannot find symbols, pointing at the imports).

Thanks for help 
Greetings
Felix

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314996/add-a-dependency-to-an-android-cordova-plugin/. Both answers should work

Comment: thanks, i don't remember how i fixed it eventually

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to you local repository.

Look ath this thread:

[I am attempting to add phonegap to my local maven repository for an android application, I'm looking for help on the steps I took](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609245/i-am-attempting-to-add-phonegap-to-my-local-maven-repository-for-an-android-appl)